# What is the use of "would" in this context

Tags: usage, conditionals, would

Could you explain what the use of "would" in this sentence is? In this context, someone opens the conversation with the question:

> A: what does this mean?
>
> > **A man who never drew but selfish breath**.
>
> B: *A man who never drew but selfish breath*.
> I **would** paraphrase this as a man who was selfish through and through.

Speaker B uses "would", is it the past of will?

Comment: The word ***would*** in your cited context is an entirely optional "hedge". It just "waters down" the assertion, which might imply that you're not actually *sure* of what you're saying, or that you don't want to risk upsetting others who might disagree with you. If you're confident of your ground, just say ***I paraphrase** this as...* and don't beast about the bush!

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm confused you say "would" is not sure, while other says it's hypothetical. But from what I have seen, the speaker seems to be sure of his answer. What do you think?

Comment: Sometimes people deliberately say things that are manifestly "untrue" (presumably in all languages, not just English). In this context, it makes no difference whether a speaker is *actually* "unsure" of what he says OR is being "deferential" and/or doesn't want to risk making a statement that someone else might disagree with. But "hypothetical" in this context is obviously just a kind of metaphorical usage when @gotube says *If I **were** to paraphrase*. There's nothing *really* hypothetical about the speaker's words there, since ***he IS paraphrasing the text!***

Comment: ...so there's no point in thinking that ***If you ask me**, I would say X is true* is somehow more "hypothetical" than the same assertion without the first four highlighted words. With or without all the hedges, caveats, and polite circumlocutions, the speaker in all cases is making the same assertion ***X is true***. All else is just window dressing.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't follow your point. If it's not hypothetical, how "would" exactly work in this case?

Comment: @FumbleFingers by the way the idea of *if you ask me* doesn't makes sense to me because the person does ask and the question is direct and open to all.                               A: How many people were at the gig last night?
B: I'd say there were about a hundred.

Would you also consider answer B to be a gloss of If you asked me, I would say ... ? Where's the conditionality exactly? The question is very real and direct.

Comment: *If it's not hypothetical, how exactly **would** the word "would" work?* OR *...how exactly **does** the word "would" work?* Both those phrasings mean *exactly* the same. In practice, *there is no "hypothetical"!* That's just how English works.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Even though both mean the same thing, there must be a difference in nuance in you example. Could you explain how "would" works in your example?

Comment: @FumbleFingers What does the term "hypothetical" exactly mean in the use of "would?"

Comment: *If you ask me, I'd say that's a dumb question!* But don't be offended - that's just as *example* of why you shouldn't necessarily interpret such things too literally. Obviously you *have* just asked me, and I *am* saying my response in the first sentence of this comment. But in the simplified world of people teaching the English language to non-native speakers, you're told that ***If*** followed by ***I'd = I would*** represents some kind of "numbered conditional" involving a "hypothetical" scenario and a hypothetical response. But neither are actually hypothetical at all - they're *real*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That makes sense. Can I also use "will" there? *I will papraphrase this as ...*

Comment: Indeed you can, yes. It's not common with this *exact* verb, but you could also forget about using an auxiliary to convey a (contextually meaningless) "hypothetical" or "future" aspect, and just use Simple Present ***I paraphrase** this as...* That's perfectly common with other verbs, such as ***I say** this is a stupid question.* Simple Present makes for a much "bolder" assertion than ***I would say** this is...*, but essentially these are all just different ways of saying the same thing.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Before the match starts, what should we use "will" or "would?" On Tuesday, we (Chelsea) take on Man City. A win **will** / **would** send us up to third.

Comment: You seem to be expecting a level of precision that English simply doesn't have (more precisely, that Anglophones don't *expect / require*). To all intents ansd purposes, it makes no difference whether the match has started or not, ***nor*** does it make any difference whether the speaker chooses to express himself using Present, Future, or Conditional - *A win **gets / will get / would get** us into the final* are all idiomatically fine.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, isn't there really any difference between *a win **will** get us into the final* and *a win **would** get us into the final*? This game is real and will be in progress. When imagining a situation, "would" would be the right choice here, wouldn't it? "Will" wouldn't be appropriate.

Comment: You don't seem to be taking in what I say. I'm sorry, but I can't explain things any more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

No, "would" here expresses "a conjecture, opinion, or hope."

It's one of the different usages of the word "would".

[Cambridge Dictionary defines this usage as:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/would)

> used to express an opinion in a polite way without being forceful

Answer (score 0):

"Would" in that context is the same as in the unreal future conditional, commonly known as "*second conditional*", but there's no "if"-clause. So it is not the past of "will".

The question itself is about the meaning. B's answer is by way of paraphrasing, so they mean:

> **If I were paraphrasing this sentence**, I would paraphrase this as a man who was selfish through and through, **so that's what it means**.

If we use "will" instead, it doesn't directly answer the question. It indicates deciding on the spot to paraphrase the sentence in that way, but never tying it back to the question. It obviously does give an answer, but indirectly, without saying it's the answer.

Comment: Can we also use "will" in that sentence? Why "would" is always used, not "will".

Comment: See Mohit's answer.  _Would_ makes B's answer a polite suggestion rather than a claim that 'this is the only right way to do it'.

Comment: @KateBunting But "will" can also be used in that sentence, doesn't it?

Comment: @Nyambek, the way *will define* is used by native speakers it implies that its speaker controls the meaning about to be assigned. And it is prospective, establishing how the word being discussed **will be** used and interpreted in what follows. With *would define* it has the sense of, “If I were pressed to describe how it **is being** used and interpreted, here’s what I’d say.”

Comment: "_Will_ can also be used in that sentence, **can't it**?" It wouldn't be grammatically incorrect to use _will_.

Comment: @KateBunting Well, why isn't "will" correct?

Comment: I said it wouldn't be **incorrect** - that is, there is no grammatical reason not to use it.  We mostly use _would_ in sentences like that for the reasons explained above.

Comment: @KateBunting But a native speaker said "will" would be incorrect because it indicates the future (something is going to happen). You said it's correct. Thiis is what is puzzling me.

Comment: Indicating the future doesn't make it _grammatically_ incorrect, but it is not a natural, idiomatic thing to say in that context.

Comment: @KateBunting What does "hypothetical" exactly mean in the use of "would?"

Comment: "If you were to ask me, I would say that..." As others have said, in this example it isn't literally hypothetical because A _did_ ask B, but _would_ is being used in the same way, to express a polite hesitancy.

Answer (score -1):

I would paraphrase this as a man who was selfish through and through.(here  the subject's belief/expectation/thinking/inclination/willingness of paraphrasing the statement in question).

The speaker is not sure of the statement . He said it carefully (but not certainly) because he don't know of its correctness.